# QR Code Tracking with Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

We would like to track clicks on QR codes on behalf of a client. They have their own analytics account but we would like to track the clicks to determine whether a QR code is required on future campaigns.

We initially thought that we would provide a URL to a page on our server which would track the click and re-direct to the relevant link, but we have also read about Urchin tracking modules and wondered whether these could be used in this scenario instead as a less labour intensive method? Does anyone have any experience with this? If so could you advise on best practice?

Answer (score 2):

If you have an access to their GA account, UTMs will be most efficient.

Encode as QR code destination URL with additional parameters utm_source, utm_medium and optional utm_campaign eg.

```
www.example.com/landing_page.html?utm_source=QRcode&utm_medium=poster&utm_campaign=february2015
```

Then in Acquisiton -> All Traffic -> Source/Medium report you'll see "QRcode / poster" for that traffic (without tagging it will be counted as a direct).